# .htaccess URL redirection appending query string with target URL

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, query-string

I am new to `.htaccess` redirect.

I have a source URL with too many parameters query string.

Source

```
http://localhost/se/karriar/?utm_source=A_candy_box&utm_medium=Printed_media&
utm_term=2013&utm_content=Want_a_fresh_start_to_your_career%3F&
utm_campaign=Mint_pastille_campaign
```

Target: `http://www.sample-website.com`

When I tried to call source URL its getting redirected along with query string as like below.

```
http://www.sample-website.com?utm_source=A_candy_box&utm_medium=Printed_media&
utm_term=2013&utm_content=Want_a_fresh_start_to_your_career%3F&
utm_campaign=Mint_pastille_campaign
```

I have written the below script in `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?localhost$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^utm_source=A_candy_box&utm_medium=Printed_media&utm_term=2013&utm_content=Want_a_fresh_start_to_your_career%3F&utm_campaign=Mint_pastille_campaign$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^se/karriar(.*)$ http://www.sample-website.com [R=301,L,NC] `
```

I would like to not appending query strings in the targeted URL. Can you any one help me?

Comment: You have not specify what you are expecting?

Comment: +2 for prompting it. I have edited my question.

Comment: Are you expecting this `http://www.sample-website.com` only when being redirected from `localhost`?

Comment: @RahilWazir yes you are right. (note: i mentioned localhost for example only i will replace the localhost with my company domain name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `.htaccess` with this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?localhost$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^utm_source=A_candy_box&utm_medium=Printed_media&utm_term=2013&utm_content=Want_a_fresh_start_to_your_career%3F&utm_campaign=Mint_pastille_campaign$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^se/karriar(.*)$ http://www.sample-website.com? [R=301,L,NC]
```

Append `?` after your target domain.

Comment: Bravo! its working. That ? question mark was missing. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi All, a little more help will be very helpful. The "%3F" characters are creating problem in this URL redirection. I tested that by removing that "%3F" characters and laso changing that to question mark (?) symbol etc... Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @user26258 Create a new instance of this question please.